# How can i make it follow my exact location using geolocation?

Tags: javascript, geolocation

i need to make a restaurant finder.. but to do that i need to be able to locate my users.. i have been having a hard time figuring out on how to geolocate them and pinpoint their location on the map and find restaurants near them..please help me.. i am new to this

**First js code**

```js
var map, places, iw;
var markers = [];
var searchTimeout;
var centerMarker;
var autocomplete;
var hostnameRegexp = new RegExp('^https?://.+?/');

function initialize() {
  var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(37.786906, -122.410156);
  var myOptions = {
    zoom: 15,
    center: myLatlng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  }
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), myOptions);
  places = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'tilesloaded', tilesLoaded);

  document.getElementById('keyword').onkeyup = function(e) {
    if (!e) var e = window.event;
    if (e.keyCode != 13) return;
    document.getElementById('keyword').blur();
    search(document.getElementById('keyword').value);
  }

  var typeSelect = document.getElementById('type');
  typeSelect.onchange = function() {
    search();
  };

  var rankBySelect = document.getElementById('rankBy');
  rankBySelect.onchange = function() {
    search();
  };

}

function tilesLoaded() {
  search();
  google.maps.event.clearListeners(map, 'tilesloaded');
  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', searchIfRankByProminence);
  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'dragend', search);
}

function searchIfRankByProminence() {
  if (document.getElementById('rankBy').value == 'prominence') {
    search();
  }
}

function search() {
  clearResults();
  clearMarkers();

  if (searchTimeout) {
    window.clearTimeout(searchTimeout);
  }
  searchTimeout = window.setTimeout(reallyDoSearch, 500);
}

function reallyDoSearch() {
  var type = document.getElementById('type').value;
  var keyword = document.getElementById('keyword').value;
  var rankBy = document.getElementById('rankBy').value;

  var search = {};

  if (keyword) {
    search.keyword = keyword;
  }

  if (type != 'establishment') {
    search.types = [type];
  }

  if (rankBy == 'distance' && (search.types || search.keyword)) {
    search.rankBy = google.maps.places.RankBy.DISTANCE;
    search.location = map.getCenter();
    centerMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: search.location,
      animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
      map: map
    });
  } else {
    search.bounds = map.getBounds();
  }

  places.search(search, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
      for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
        var icon = 'number_' + (i + 1) + '.png';
        markers.push(new google.maps.Marker({
          position: results[i].geometry.location,
          animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
          icon: icon
        }));
        google.maps.event.addListener(markers[i], 'click', getDetails(results[i], i));
        window.setTimeout(dropMarker(i), i * 100);
        addResult(results[i], i);
      }
    }
  });
}

function clearMarkers() {
  for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
    markers[i].setMap(null);
  }
  markers = [];
  if (centerMarker) {
    centerMarker.setMap(null);
  }
}

function dropMarker(i) {
  return function() {
    if (markers[i]) {
      markers[i].setMap(map);
    }
  }
}

function addResult(result, i) {
  var results = document.getElementById('results');
  var tr = document.createElement('tr');
  tr.style.backgroundColor = (i % 2 == 0 ? '#F0F0F0' : '#FFFFFF');
  tr.onclick = function() {
    google.maps.event.trigger(markers[i], 'click');
  };

  var iconTd = document.createElement('td');
  var nameTd = document.createElement('td');
  var icon = document.createElement('img');
  icon.src = 'number_' + (i + 1) + '.png';
  icon.setAttribute('class', 'placeIcon');
  icon.setAttribute('className', 'placeIcon');
  var name = document.createTextNode(result.name);
  iconTd.appendChild(icon);
  nameTd.appendChild(name);
  tr.appendChild(iconTd);
  tr.appendChild(nameTd);
  results.appendChild(tr);
}

function clearResults() {
  var results = document.getElementById('results');
  while (results.childNodes[0]) {
    results.removeChild(results.childNodes[0]);
  }
}

function getDetails(result, i) {
  return function() {
    places.getDetails({
      reference: result.reference
    }, showInfoWindow(i));
  }
}

function showInfoWindow(i) {
  return function(place, status) {
    if (iw) {
      iw.close();
      iw = null;
    }

    if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
      iw = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: getIWContent(place)
      });
      iw.open(map, markers[i]);
    }
  }
}

function getIWContent(place) {
  var content = '';
  content += '<table>';
  content += '<tr class="iw_table_row">';
  content += '<td style="text-align: left"><img class="hotelIcon" src="' + place.icon + '"/></td>';
  content += '<td><b><a href="' + place.url + '">' + place.name + '</a></b></td></tr>';
  content += '<tr class="iw_table_row"><td class="iw_attribute_name">Address:</td><td>' + place.vicinity + '</td></tr>';
  if (place.formatted_phone_number) {
    content += '<tr class="iw_table_row"><td class="iw_attribute_name">Telephone:</td><td>' + place.formatted_phone_number + '</td></tr>';
  }
  if (place.rating) {
    var ratingHtml = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      if (place.rating < (i + 0.5)) {
        ratingHtml += '&#10025;';
      } else {
        ratingHtml += '&#10029;';
      }
    }
    content += '<tr class="iw_table_row"><td class="iw_attribute_name">Rating:</td><td><span id="rating">' + ratingHtml + '</span></td></tr>';
  }
  if (place.website) {
    var fullUrl = place.website;
    var website = hostnameRegexp.exec(place.website);
    if (website == null) {
      website = 'http://' + place.website + '/';
      fullUrl = website;
    }
    content += '<tr class="iw_table_row"><td class="iw_attribute_name">Website:</td><td><a href="' + fullUrl + '">' + website + '</a></td></tr>';
  }
  content += '</table>';
  return content;
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false -->
```

```
html {
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)), url(superb-seaside-restaurant-hd-wallpaper-506329.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover
}
#form {
  font: 20px"Walkway SemiBold";
  letter-spacing: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  padding-bottom: 3px;
  padding-right: 4px;
  padding-top: 3px;
  height: 35%;
  width: 50%;
  background: #ccc;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  /* Fallback for older browsers without RGBA-support */
  background: rgba(204, 204, 204, 0.5);
  float: left;
}
#header {
  font: 20px"Josefin Slab";
  letter-spacing: 10px;
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #000;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 3px;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 1255px;
  background: #ccc;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  /* Fallback for older browsers without RGBA-support */
  background: rgba(204, 204, 204, 0.5);
}
#map_canvas {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px #bfdeff;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #bfdeff;
  box-shadow: 0 0 7px #bfdeff;
  float: right;
  height: 500px;
  width: 593px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-right: 3px;
  vertical-align: top;
}
#listing {
  font: 18pt"Nilland";
  letter-spacing: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 3px;
  height: 500px;
  width: 50%;
  background: #ccc;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  /* Fallback for older browsers without RGBA-support */
  background: rgba(204, 204, 204, 0.5);
  float: left;
}
#footer {
  font: 18px"Nilland-Black";
  letter-spacing: 10px;
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #000;
  text-align: right;
  padding: 5px;
  height: 27px;
  width: 1255px;
  background: #ccc;
  margin-top: 3px;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
  /* Fallback for older browsers without RGBA-support */
  background: rgba(204, 204, 204, 0.5);
  float: right;
}
.placeIcon {
  width: 32px;
  height: 37px;
  margin: 4px;
}
.hotelIcon {
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
}
#resultsTable {
  font: 16pt"Nilland-Black";
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 450px;
  margin-left: 90px;
  float: left;
  background: rgba(204, 204, 204, 0.5);
}
#rating {
  font-size: 13px;
  font-family: Arial Unicode MS;
}
#keywordsLabel {
  text-align: right;
  width: 70px;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 4px;
  position: absolute;
}
.iw_table_row {
  height: 18px;
}
.iw_attribute_name {
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
  <title>Map</title>
  <link href="working.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true&libraries=places"></script>
  <script src="C:\Users\beesumbernice\Documents\html\html\whole.js"></script>
  <script src="C:\Users\beesumbernice\Documents\html\html\this.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="header">
    <h1>
        HEADER
      </h1>
  </div>
  <div id="form">
    Keywords:
    <input id="keyword" type="text" placeholder="Mexican,Italian,Chinese..." />
    <div id="controls">
      <span id="typeLabel">
      Type:
    </span>
      <select id="type">
        <option value="bar">Bars</option>
        <option value="cafe">Cafe</option>
        <option value="restaurant" selected="selected">Restaurants</option>
      </select>
      <span id="rankByLabel">
      Rank by:
    </span>
      <select id="rankBy">
        <option value="prominence">Prominence</option>
        <option value="distance" selected="selected">Distance</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="map_canvas"></div>

  <div id="listing" style="overflow-y: scroll; height:453px;">
    <table id="resultsTable">
      <tbody id="results"></tbody>
    </table>
  </div>

  <div id="footer">
    <a href="http://mapicons.nicolasmollet.com">Maps Icons Collection</a>
    <img src="C:\Users\beesumbernice\Documents\html\html\desktop\powered-by-google-on-non-white.png" height="16" width="104"></img>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<html>
<body>
  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&libraries=places"></script>
  <script>
   function initialize(){
   var mapOptions =
  {
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    zoom: 8
  };
  if(navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
    var lat=position.coords.latitude;
    var lng=position.coords.longitude;
    var geolocate = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
    map.setCenter(geolocate);
  });
  }
   var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
    mapOptions);
 }
 google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
<div id="map-canvas" style="width:300;height:300px;border:1px solid black;">        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Check it out ["HERE"](http://jsfiddle.net/manisha21/jatm2j7w/)

Comment: it didnt show anything, even my map doesnt show anymore

Comment: try the edited code.. I had tried it.. if u r trying the code on PC then mostly it takes your IP address..

Answer (score 0):

Hope this code will help you out

```
var mapInterval;
if(navigator.geolocation) {
    var intervalTime = 5; // 5 seconds inteerval
    mapInterval = window.setInterval(function(){
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
        map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude));
    }, intervalTime*1000)
});
// Whenever you want to stop updating the location
// mapInterval
```

Comment: i placed in the function initialize() it didnt show anything

Comment: no, it just removed the map on the canvas and also makes the other js script file not work

Comment: You have placed this right below after you initialized map object, right?

Comment: yes, i did put it right below after i initialized map object